# How to set start page in Web.config file in asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, configuration, web-config

How to set start page using `Web.config` file. I have tried this code

```
<system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument enabled="true">
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="index.aspx"/>
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
```

But it did not work for me.  I have set start page by right click on page in solution explorer then choose option set as start page but how can I do it programmatically?

Comment: where did you placed this? can you post full config

Comment: It seems <defaultDocument> will work when you run web on IIS. And if you run from VS, it will redirect following the file which you set as start page.

Comment: worked for me !

Answer (score 87):

The following code worked fine for me. Kindly check other setting in your `Web.config`

```
 <system.webServer>
     <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />               
                <add value="Login.aspx"/>
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
```

Comment: @Aravin it means that it clears all informations that could be define in the files tag in other .config that affects your site.

Answer (score 7):

If your project contains a RouteConfig.cs file, then you probably need to ignore the route to the root by adding `routes.IgnoreRoute("");` in this file.

If it doen't solve your problem, try this :

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath == "~/")
        Response.Redirect("~/index.aspx");
}
```

Comment: IgnoreRoute helped

Answer (score 5):

```
I think this will help
```

```
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="index.aspx" />
        <add value="Default.htm" />
        <add value="Default.asp" />
        <add value="index.htm" />
        <add value="index.html" />
        <add value="iisstart.htm" />
        <add value="default.aspx" />
        <add value="index.php" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Why do we need to add all those? Is the order added the criteria used for displaying them?

Comment: if you have .aspx page then add only these else it can be any page depends on language you are using.

Comment: Nice. I like it 'cause one can mess around with various files just by changing the order of the default doc.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem arrised for me when I installed Kaliko CMS Nuget Package. When I removed it, it started working fine again. So, your problem could be because of a recently installed Nuget Package. Uninstall it and your solution will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

For those using MVC views by now, add a rewrite rule to your web.config:

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Redirect to front" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^$" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="/yourViewName" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Just put that in between the system.webServer tags of your configuration tags, replace yourViewName by your start page's view name (like Home), and you're done!

Works like a dream.

Answer (score -3):

You can achieve it by code also, In you Global.asax file in Session_Start event write response.redirect to your start page like following.

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Code that runs when a new session is started

            Response.Redirect("~/Index.aspx");

        }
```

You can get redirect page name from database or any other storage to change the application start page while application is running no need to edit web.config or change any IIS settings

Comment: Session_Start is called every time and you forcing a user to be redirected at any postback