# Server Error in '/' Application, Fresh Make

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, model-view-controller

So this comes up:

[image]

and I've only run it. I haven't done any kind of changes to the files whatsoever so I don't know why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have to set a startup Page.

here is two ways to do it

**Way 1**

[Using web config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20367826/how-to-set-start-page-in-webconfig-file-in-asp-net-c-sharp)

**Way 2**

> In Solution Explorer, right-click the page that you want to specify as
>   the start page, and then click Set As Start Page.

[Using Visual studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b6ckkzy(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.